# Custom Code Not Working in SharePoint Designer

Tags: jquery, custom, designer

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.
The below code doesnt seem to do anything?
(i.e. if I click on Action2Q nothing happens 
(otherAction_Y and OtherAction_N are definitely correct values)
(I just want to display two more questions if Yes Value is selected) - script src is in as well)

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var visibilityYes = "";
var visibilityNo = "none";
$(function () {

        var OtherAction_Y = 'ff101_ctl00_ctl00';
        var OtherAction_N = 'ff101_ctl00_ctl01';

        var SecondActionDropDown = "ff131_ctl00_DropDownChoice";

        var arrSecondAction = ["ActionDate2", "Action2", "Action3Q"];

        //SecondActionDropDown
        $("input[id$='" + OtherAction_Y + "']").click(function () {
            RowVisibility(arrSecondAction, visibilityYes);
        });
        $("input[id$='" + OtherAction_N + "']").click(function () {
            RowVisibility(arrSecondAction, visibilityNo);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Action Date 2 has id assigned as do others, id="ActionDate2"

Comment: Shouldn't "Action3Q" be "Action2Q" ?

Comment: Learn to use your browsers F12 Developers Tools and see if the click event gets attached

Comment: Action3Q is correct, I am displaying another Question (Action2Q is showing all the time). I can access F12 dev tools in chrome, can I check how do I see if click event working? If I use click element and click on Yes I do get click - input#(with a load more number in front)ff101_ctl00_ctl00. I do get this as an error - Uncaught ReferenceError: RowVisibility is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery and `$(document).ready()` you do not need that initial `$(function()` wrapper.

And even if you were going to use it, if you have copied your code accurately in this post, you are missing the closing bracket and parentheses for that.

Comment: I have changed code in original is that right? Still same issue

Comment: No, you took out the wrong line.  you should remove the line `$(function () {` and replace the line `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: Now got it working! I needed to add a function for RowVisibility, thanks so much for all your help!